# typescript getter functions and visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am writing getter function in my typescript classes in visual studio. I like getter function because I feel it cleans up my code, there is one situation I want to fix though.

```
class Foo {

  doWork(){
    console.log(this.bar);
    this.bar = 2;
  }

  get bar(){
    return 1;
  }

}
```

the first line in doWork is correct and there is no complaints from visual studio. Its the second line that I want to fix. When the code is transpiled it throws an error in the client like it should but visual studio doesnt know to complain and underline the second line. I was wondering if there was some visual studio setting that could get it to say that the second line is incorrect

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and Typescript do you use? Visual Studio 2015 and TS 2.1 highlights it as error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHT2L.png

Comment: i am still using TS 1.8, thank you

Comment: Why are you using 1.8? Try to upgrade.

Comment: we are in the process of upgrading to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was solved in TypeScript version 2.0. For more insformations read TypeScript's GitHub issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12.

You need to upgrade your TypeScript compiler. Download new TypeScript installer from http://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html#download-links (Visual Studio 2015 link) and just install.